# How to remove dataclass attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass like this:

```
@dataclass
class Bla:
    arg1: Optional[int] = None
    arg2: Optional[str] = None
    arg3: Optional[Dict[str, str]] = None
```

I want this behavior:

```
>>> bla = Bla(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None)
>>> asdict(bla)
{'arg1': None, 'arg2': None, 'arg3': None}

>>> bla = Bla()
{}
```

In this specific case, I could use a `dict`, but I would lose the possibility of have type-hints (and use mypy)

So I tried this:

```
class none:
    ...

@dataclass
class Bla:
    arg1: Union[none, int] = none()
    arg2: Union[none, str] = none()
    arg3: Union[none, Dict[str, str]] = none()

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        for k, v in self.__dict__.copy().items():
            if isinstance(v, none):
                delattr(self, k)
```

But the result was:

```
>>> asdict(Bla())
{'arg1': <__main__.none object at 0x7f71bc0159b0>, 'arg2': <__main__.none object at 0x7f71bc015a90>, 'arg3': <__main__.none object at 0x7f71bc015ac8>}
```

I expected an empty `dict`

If try:

```
>>> a = Bla(None, None, None)
>>> del a.__dict__["arg1"]
>>> asdict(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/(....)/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataclasses.py", line 1011, in asdict
    return _asdict_inner(obj, dict_factory)
  File "/home/(...)/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataclasses.py", line 1018, in _asdict_inner
    value = _asdict_inner(getattr(obj, f.name), dict_factory)
AttributeError: 'Bla' object has no attribute 'arg1'
```

**How can I dynamically remove attributes from a dataclass object in a way that I could use `asdict` after that?**

Comment: All of the methods generated by dataclass expect the instances to have the same structure.  So `asdict`, `str`, etc. won't work for instances that are missing attributes.  What's your use case?  It doesn't sound like dataclasses are a good fit for your problem.

Comment: Dataclasses are simply not designed to do that. Use a plain class and implement it yourself.

Comment: I edited my answer. The use case is lots of models that I want to store in classes. Data classes are very convenient for this. If I find a way to ignore or remove any element that is not explicitly passed in the constructor, it would be perfect.

Comment: "Data classes are very convenient for this" - but not for deleting attributes. As others have said, dataclasses share their structure in their class objectr. The instance structure is not consulted when calling `asdict`, it's [`__dataclass_fields__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0bcbfa43d55d9558cdcb256d8998366281322080/Lib/dataclasses.py#L1006) which resides on `cls` and not on `self`.

Answer (score 12):

If you plan to use `asdict`, the important part isn't deleting the attribute from the instance (which is where e.g. `vars` would check), but deleting the attribute from the instance's `__dataclass_fields__`.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional, Dict, cast

SENTINEL = cast(None, object())  # have a sentinel that pretends to be 'None'


@dataclass
class Bla:
    arg1: Optional[int] = SENTINEL
    arg2: Optional[str] = SENTINEL
    arg3: Optional[Dict[str, str]] = SENTINEL

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.__dataclass_fields__ = {
            k: v for k, v in self.__dataclass_fields__.items()
            if getattr(self, k) is not SENTINEL
        }
```

Some tests:

```py
>>> from dataclasses import asdict
>>> asdict(Bla())
{}
>>> asdict(Bla(None, None))
{'arg1': None, 'arg2': None}
>>> asdict(Bla(1, 'foo', None))
{'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 'foo', 'arg3': None}
```

---

With a slightly different `__post_init__`, you can also delete the attribute's value from the instance itself. This will save a little RAM as well as remove the attribute from `vars`, but `getattr` will still find the class variable, which might end up making things quite confusing:

```py
[...]
    def __post_init__(self):
        for field_name in [*self.__dataclass_fields__]:
            if getattr(self, field_name) is SENTINEL:
                del self.__dataclass_fields__[field_name]
                delattr(self, field_name)
[...]
>>> bla = Bla()
>>> asdict(bla)
{}
>>> vars(bla)
{}
>>> bla.arg1
<object object at 0x7f2c248a49e0>
```

Comment: When your purpose is to produce a dict or json, this answer is helpful. It is unimportant if the intermediate attributes exist, as long as asdict produces the desired structure. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

My question was about how to remove attributes from a [`dataclasses.dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-level-decorators-classes-and-functions) object in a way that I could use the function [`dataclasses.asdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) to generate dictionaries.

My use case was lots of models that I'd like to store in an easy-to-serialize and type-hinted way, but with the possibility of omitting elements (without having any default values). My first approach was to figure out a way to remove any item that I was not explicitly passed in the `dataclass` constructor.

However, as [Patrick and Arne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58119758/how-to-remove-dataclass-attributes#comment102633775_58119758)  point out, wisely,  that's not the right thing to try to accomplish with `dataclasses`.

The best way I found to solve my use case was to use [`TypedDict`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#typeddict) from the `typing_extensions` module, that, with [PEP 589](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/), will be part of the standard library in the module `typing` in [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict).

In Python 3.8:

```
from typing import TypedDict, Dict

class Bla(TypedDict):
    arg1: int
    arg2: str
    arg3: Dict[str, str]
```

In other versions you have to install `typing_extensions` module:

```
pip install typing-extensions
```

then:

```
from typing_extensions import TypedDict
```

Let's try:

```
>>> Bla(arg1=1, arg2="bla", arg3={"bla":"bla"})
{'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 'bla', 'arg3': {'bla': 'bla'}}

>>> Bla(arg1=1, arg2="bla")
{'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 'bla'}

>>> Bla(arg1=1)
{'arg1': 1}
```

Very elegant and fits perfectly in my use case.

The only drawback is that `TypedDict` doesn't support default values yet. There is a [PR](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6131) for that and I'm hopeful they will do something about.